# Creating a Visual Studio 2010 Item Template with multiple folders and files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, itemtemplate, visual-studio-sdk

I've been reading info on this the past few days and though I've made some progress, I'm still a bit lost.

I have created a collection of classes, files, and folders that together I want to join together as a Visual Studio Item Template.

Think of it as a "module".

The idea is that they add this "Module Item Template" and Visual Studio will insert the folders and files and rename them accordingly.

This is not a PROJECT template it is an ITEM TEMPLATE, because it needs to be added to an already existing project they are working on, within that project (not as a separate one).

By using the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK Item Template Template, I've ALMOST got it.

The problem is that when I use the $safeitemname$ I get different names in each class.

I was hoping that when they add the item, and name it say "MyModule", the value $safeitemname$ would be "MyModule".

this isn't happening. Instead, each generated class file gets a different value for $safeitemname$ that matches the generated file name.

So for example if I have a MyModuleConfig.cs class, and I have another class file setup like this:

```
public class $safeitemname$Config
{
}
```

instead of getting the Item name that the user entered "MyModule" together with config, the class gets named "MyModuleConfigConfig".

How can I tell it to only use the original name that the user entered when they created the module in the Add Item dialog using the template?

Answer (score 1):

okay literally seconds after posting this I discovered that I should be using the $fileinputname$ instead!

this appears to be exactly what I wanted, thanks, self!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! That was very helpful!